# jquery, issue with toggle

Tags: jquery, toggle, mouseover

When the mouse is over a div .frame I want to toggle a div .content inside of that div .frame
And when the mouse is out .frame I want .content to toggle again and to remove.

It's working but I have several issues, first when the mouse is out .frame, .content is not toggeling but it just removing without any effects.

Then when the mouse is over .content (which is inside .frame), .content is removing...

my code is:

```
$(document).on('mouseover', '.frame', function() {
    var el = $(this);
    el.find('.inside').append('<div class="content"></div>');
    var content = $('.content:last');
    content.hide();
    content.html('aaaaaaaaaaaa<br>aaaaaaaaaaaa<br>aaaaaaaaaaaa<br>aaaaaaaaaaaa<br>');
    $('.content').toggle(300);
}).on('mouseout', function() {
    var content = $('.content:last');
    $('.content').stop().toggle(300).remove();
});
```

here a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HAxPB/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a callback function to ***wait until the effect has finished***. And use `mouseenter`, `mouseleave` instead. There is also one small problem with the code at: `.on('mouseout', function() {,` it should be `.on('mouseleave',",frame", function() {,`

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.frame', function() {
    if ( $('.content').length > 0){
        return;
    }
    var el = $(this);
    el.find('.inside').append('<div class="content"></div>');
    var content = $('.content:last');
    content.hide();
    content.html('aaaaaaaaaaaa<br>aaaaaaaaaaaa<br>aaaaaaaaaaaa<br>aaaaaaaaaaaa<br>');
    $('.content').toggle(300);
}).on('mouseleave','.frame', function() {
    var content = $('.content:last');
    $('.content').stop().toggle(300,function(){
        $(this).remove();
    })
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HAxPB/22/)

Comment: I see what you mean, but now in your demo when the mouse is over .content, an other .content is toggeling again and again and again

Comment: but when the mouse is entereing and leaving realy fast the div, a lot of .content are appending instead of just one